# How to define all custom elements before any constructors are called?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

I have two custom elements: `One` and `Two`. `One` has a function. `Two` has a child of `One` and tries to call that function in its constructor. It says that the function does not exist if I call `customElements.define()` on `Two` before `One`. However, if I define `One` before `Two`, it works just fine.

In my actual project, I do not have control of the order in which they are defined, and by default they are being defined in the wrong order.

I tried calling the function in the `connectedCallback()`, but this also failed.

When exactly is the constructor called?

Is there any way that I can make sure they are all defined before any constructors are called?

```js
class One extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    console.log('one constructor')
  }
  
  myFunc() {
    console.log('it worked!')
  }
}

class Two extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    console.log('two constructor')
    
    this.innerHTML = '<my-one></my-one>'
    this.myOne = document.querySelector('my-one')
    
    // this part fails
    this.myOne.myFunc()
  }
  
  connectedCallback() {
    // this also fails
    this.myOne.myFunc()
  }
}

// this works
// customElements.define("my-one", One)
// customElements.define("my-two", Two)

// this breaks
customElements.define("my-two", Two)
customElements.define("my-one", One)
```

```html
<my-two></my-two>
```

Comment: Element two relies on element one existing, so you kind of _need_ to wait until that element has been defined. The modern solution to do that is to define each custom element in its own module, and making sure to start the module for two with `import One from "./one.js";` so that the browser can force the parse order, even if the network load order is completely different.

Comment: As for when the constructor is called: the constructor is called without arguments during the [element upgrade part](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#upgrades) of registering the custom element, so there is no such thing as "declaring" custom element without constructing one: part of the definition process is verifying that the element _can_ be built, by literally building one.

Comment: (Some more good advice can be found over on https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element-conformance : hold off on that innerHTML and selector code until `connectedCallback`, for example. Don't do that in the constructor)

Comment: You may also want to consider the fact that, at least in Chrome, setting `innerHTML` _is actually an `async` operation_. Therefore, the line right below it might not find the item unless wrapped in, say, a `setTimeout` or something (to push it onto the JS Event Loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is all about the life-cycle of a Web Component and when a tag is upgraded from an `HTMLUnknownElement` to your actual Component

A component is defined in two steps.

1) Definition of a class
2) Calling `customElements.define`

Yes these two can be *written* together:

```
customElements.define('dog-food', class extends HTMLElement{});
```

But the class definition still happens before `customElements.define` is called.

Elements are only upgraded to a custom element when two things have happened:

1) The Custom Element must be defined by using `customElements.define` and
2) The Custom Element must either
  1) be instantiated using `document.createElement` or `new MyElement`
  2) be added to the DOM tree

This example has the element placed into the DOM but it is not defined for 1 second.

I display the constructor before it is defined and then, again, after it is defined.

```js
class One extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('one constructor');
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = "I have upgraded";
  }
}

let el = document.querySelector('my-one');

setTimeout(() => {
  customElements.define("my-one", One);
  console.log('after: ', el.constructor.toString().substr(0,30));
}, 1000);

console.log('before: ', el.constructor);
```

```html
<my-one>I am just a simple element</my-one>
```

In your code you use `innerHTML` to "load" `<my-one>`. But since `<my-two>` may not "really" be in the DOM by the time the constructor is called then the `innerHTML` will not be in the DOM and, thus, `<my-one>` will not get upgraded yet.

One thing you can do is to wait until the `<my-two>` component is really placed into the DOM by waiting to change the `innerHTML` in the `connectedCallback` function:

```js
class One extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('one constructor');
  }
  
  myFunc() {
    console.log('it worked!');
  }
}

class Two extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('two constructor');
  }
  
  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = '<my-one></my-one>';
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.myOne = document.querySelector('my-one');
      this.myOne.myFunc();
    });
  }
}

customElements.define("my-two", Two)
customElements.define("my-one", One)
```

```html
<my-two></my-two>
```

You will notice that I had to still place the call to the function in `<my-one>` into a `setTimeout` call. This is because the `<my-one>` element can not be upgraded until AFTER your `connectedCallback` function exists. Upgrading needs a chance to run and it will not run in the middle of your function.

Another way to do it is by calling the constructor for `<my-one>` directly:

```js
class One extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('one constructor');
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = "one";
  }

  myFunc() {
    console.log('it worked!');
  }
}

class Two extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('two constructor');
  }
  
  connectedCallback() {
    customElements.whenDefined('my-one').then(() => {
      this.myOne = document.createElement('my-one');
      this.append(this.myOne);
      this.myOne.myFunc();
    });
  }
}

customElements.define("my-two", Two);
customElements.define("my-one", One);
```

```html
<my-two></my-two>
```

Here you will notice that I had to add a call to `customElements.whenDefined`. This will wait until `<my-one>` to actually be defined before it attempts to instantiate it. Once it is defined then you can create it and call the member function right away.

One last thing. There are rules for what you should and should not do while in a constructor for a Web Component. They are defined here https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#custom-element-conformance

But one thing I will point out is that you are not supposed to touch or change any attributes or child elements in the constructor. Mainly because there are no attribute or any child elements when the Web Component is constructed. Those are changed and added after the fact.

Comment: w3c link is 404